# Distributing data/stream to all connected sockets

Tags: sockets

I have written a multithreaded socket server in java that handles multiple concurrent TCP connections (clients), each client has a separate Thread. 
I have to distribute a special type of packet coming from any client to all other clients connected. Here is a snippet of my Server class

```
public class MyServer {
    public List<MyClient> clients;

    public void distributePacket(MyPacket pkt){
        //implementation for sending packet to each connected client
    }
}
```

my current implementation of distributePacket is like this

```
for (int a=0;a<clients.size();a++){
    if(clients.get(a).getId()!=pkt.getClientId(){
        clients.get(a).write(pkt.data,pkt.length);
    }
}
```

But I think it will decrease the performance with large number of clients.

Can you guys suggest any more appropriate logic to achieve this task ? thanks

Comment: Compared to what? You have to write the data, and you have to do so to each client. You could multi-thread it, but there is still only one network.

Comment: **Compared to what**
compared to what i m currently doing. Single loop send data to all clients

**You could multi-thread it**
how ? separate thread for each client to send data ?